# Protocol error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, protocols, chmod, laravel-artisan

I am using **Laravel 5.6.23**

This is my error message:

```
UnexpectedValueException    
There is no existing directory at "C:\timereg-project\Laravel\storage\logs" and its not buildable: Protocol error
```

The directory **logs** do in fact exist in my Laravel project.
I have tried this which is not working:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

I have tried this which is also not working:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

If I try this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

I get error

```
chmod: cannot access 'Laravel/storage/logs': no such file or directory
```

Commands which is not working:

```
composer update
```

What can i do about this? It feels like i am totally blocked from the **logs** folder.

[image: Full error message]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all is set correctly and permissions it should work. Try this command you missed:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: You are a GOD!
Thanks it work like a charm!
Will set this comment as the answer :)

Comment: glad it helped :DD